# Page.User.Identity.Name returns empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some Page.User.Identity.Name always returns an empty string.  Any ideas.  I simply want to print it to the screen.  IIS is set for integrated windows security.

Response.Write("Name = " + Page.User.Identity.Name);

Oops just noticed i hadnt set authentication to windows auth.  Silly me

Comment: why did you submit this if it wasn't a question?

Comment: If you answered your own question... answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops just noticed i hadnt set authentication to windows auth. Silly me